# Getting a response status code with lua-request

Tags: http, lua, request

How is it possible to get the response status code of a request using [lua-http](https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http) ?
If that is not possible with it what module/library should i use ?

Comment: [lua-http/examples/](https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http/tree/master/examples)

Answer (score 0):

From the docs :

```lua
local http_request = require "http.request"
local headers, stream = assert(http_request.new_from_uri("http://example.com"):go())
print(headers:get ":status")
```

Comment: Avoid posting code-only-answers without explanations, please add more details to your answer to help the OP understand, and also the future researchers/readers which will encounter the same problem.